# how import ispell dictionary into hunspell?

Tags: spell-checking, aspell, hunspell, ispell

I downloaded the dictionary : american-huge for ispell, and I'm trying to extract the words list from it.  I tough of importing it into aspell and use aspell to dump it, but I want't able to :(

I read that hunspell I could use hunspell in my program, so the next option was to use hunspell dictionaries, but the problem is that I didn't find the equivalent dictionay (huge) for hunspell.

There is a way to import the ispell dictionary into hunspell ?